# Does Omega retain some of its boss form abilities as party member in the non-Japanese versions?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I saw in some videos that are in Japanese that sometimes when there are lots of enemies he uses his lightning shock from his Adena and his flamethrower, but I haven't seen either of those two skills being used in any version out of Japan.  I am just asking to make sure if they exist also in non-Japanese versions.

Comment: I don't know what this is, but it sounds great.

Answer (score 1):

They do exist, must be with Noel and Serah on Rav and have the paradigm on wide, while Omega is the only com.